# Counting Uncategorized and Unknown Names

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a list of about 100k names. These are people’s names, company names, etc. the names can be an exact match or vary in some ways . I also have addresses but the addresses may be wrong or may not exist. I need to collect and count each name for an analysis. Here is an example set,

```
Bank America, N.A
BOA
Bank f Amerca
America Bank
Wells Fargo Bank
Wells Fargo
Wells Fargo, N.A
Fargo Bank
```

For `Bank of America`, the count would be three, as `America Bank` is something different. For `Wells Fargo` the count would be three as `Fargo Bank` is something different.

Edit:

Rather than using machine learning, another option would be to use fuzzy matching. I've looked at the difflib and fuzzywuzzy libraries but the problem is that I have no reference list; the logic itself would have to figure out the reference (which is why I thought machine learning is the answer).

So as an exercise, here is a second data example,

```
John Smith - First instance found, therefore, this is labeled as ID 1
Chase Bank - First instance found, this is labeled as ID 2
John J. Smith - Similar to John Smith, therefore, this is labeled as ID 1
BOA - First instance found, this is labeled as ID 3
Bank of America - Not similar to BOA, therefore labeled as ID 4 (Technically this is BOA but the system will not know this at first)
BOA, N.A. - Similar to BOA, therefore labeled as ID 3
```

Now let's take `BOA` and `Bank of America`. How would the program know that these are the same? It wouldn't, so I would need to come back and indicate that `BOA` and `Bank of America` are the same. If we go the machine learning route, I could create a new field and manually indicate that `BOA` and `Bank of America` are the same and retry the process again to get better results. But lets say we want to go the easy route and not do this, is there a python library that will help me?

I more need a good starting off point than actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would still like to attempt this with machine learning but I have created a Python solution that I will implement using FuzzyWuzzy.

I will be generating a dynamic reference list based on a loop through the DB. So, for loop 1, I will create a unique ID for that Text. This will be stored in a table. In loop 2, I will look at the records in the new table and attempt to match it, if there is a match, that same ID will be assigned to the next record. If nothing is found that text will be added to the new table with a new unique ID. . . and so on. This method avoids machine learning and it will probably be good enough for the current set of requirements.

Edit:
I am adding an additional table so the tables will look as follows

```
Table 1 = Unprocessed Source Data
Table 2 = Unique Names
Table 3 = All derivations of Unique Names
```

I am also getting a unique list to start of the most common names and adding it to Table 2 and 3. This will simply be a starting off point.